# What we know about sylow subgroups of $G/P$?

Tags: finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $P$ be it's normal $p$-subgroup. What we can say about the sylow subgroup of $G/P$?

For example if we know that a $q$-sylow $(q\neq p)$ subgroup of $G/P$ is normal and non abelian what we can say about $q$-sylow subgroup of $G$?

Comment: Thanks for all tips. I think it is better that I ask my question in this way: Suppose $H/P=QP/P$ be a $q$-sylow subgroup of $G/P$ where $q\neq p$ and $Q$ is $q$-sylow subgroup of $G$. Also we know that $H/P$ is normal and non abelian. what we can say about $Q$.

Answer (score 3):

**Note**: my answer does not assume that $P$ is a normal $p$-group (I didn't see this when I first read the question), but merely any normal subgroup.

If $q: G \rightarrow G/P$ is the quotient map, then for every Sylow $p$-subgroup $S$ of $G$, the image $q(S)$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G/P$.  This is [easy to see](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Quotient_of_Sylow_P-Subgroup): one just has to check that it has the right order.

From this it follows that if $G$ has a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup $S$, then the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G/P$ are normal (so in fact there is exactly one).  Also, if $S$ is commutative, so is $q(S)$.  The converse clearly does not hold: e.g. suppose $G = P$ is a nonabelian $p$-group.  (However if $P$ is a $p$-group and $S$ is a Sylow $q$-subgroup for a prime $q \neq p$, then $q(S) = SP/P \cong S/(S \cap P) \cong S$, as in Boris Novikov' answer.)

Comment: I think we've got all bases covered ($P$ a not necessarily normal subgroup of $G$, Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G/P$, and Sylow $q$-subgroups of $G/P$ for $q\neq p$) with the three answers here!

Comment: @AmiteshDatta, I think $\,P\,$ **must** be a normal subgroup. Pete's *not* assuming it necessarily is a $\,p-$subgroup.

Comment: I agree with @DonAntonio.

Comment: Yes, @DonAntonio, that was a typo on my part.

Answer (score 2):

Let $Q$ be a $q$-Sylow subgroup in $G$, $Q'$ be its image in $G/P$. Since $P\cap Q=1$, then $Q\cong Q'$ (so if $Q'$ is Abelian, $Q$ is also).

If $Q'$ is normal, $Q$ can be n0n-n0rmal. An example: for $G=S_3$, $P$ its Sylow 3-group, $Q'=G/P$.

Comment: That is right, but I have some information abut $q$-sylow subgroups of $G/P$ and I want to know about the sylow subgroups of $G$.

Comment: Hi @Adeleh, the Sylow $q$-subgroups of $G/P$ (for any prime $q$) are precisely the homomorphic images of Sylow $q$-subgroups of $G$ under the canonical map $G\to G/P$. E.g., see Pete's excellent answer below as well as my answer.

Comment: @Adeleh: I see, you take two examples of properties: 'interior' (abelian) and 'exterior' (normal). In the first case it is OK since $Q\cong Q'$, in the second case you have to impose some additional conditions on $G$ or $G/P$ (a naive example: if $G$ is Abelian then normality is transferred from $G'$ to $G$).

Answer (score 1):

The key point is that the Sylow $q$-subgroups of $G/P$ (for any prime $q$) are precisely the homomorphic images of the Sylow $q$-subgroups of $G$ under the canonical homomorphism $G\to G/P$. Also, homomorphic images of abelian groups are always abelian. E.g., this is elaborated in both Pete's and Boris' excellent answers. I've provided details in my answer below.

Firstly, let's consider the case of primes $q\neq p$: any Sylow $q$-subgroup of $G/P$ (in fact, any subgroup of $G/P$) is of the form $H/P$ for some subgroup $H$ of $G$ containing $P$. Now, $H=QP$ where $Q$ is a Sylow $q$-subgroup of $H$. (Why?) Since $Q$ is also a Sylow $q$-subgroup of $G$ (why?), it follows that $H/P$ equals the image of $Q$ under the canonical homomorphism $G\to G/P$.

Now let's consider the case $q=p$. If a $p$-subgroup $P\subseteq G$ is normal in $G$, then $P$ must be contained in all Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$. (**Exercise**; use the Sylow theorems.) The intersection of all Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ is referred to as the **$p$-core** of $G$ and is the unique maximal normal $p$-subgroup of $G$.

Therefore, the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G/P$ are precisely the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ which contain $P$.

I hope this helps!